# How to remove the duplicate design pane in split view in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I prefer Split view (and I have to set it each time I open a view...)

On the right side of the split, there is a useful left one and a duplicate one that I never look at in my work. I follow design spec and must often write pure styles as XML to carry it across views.

This one.

[image: right half of split view]

How do I remove it?

The problem is rather that I create a branch from a task and edit both code and XML and would like AS to work with me: Always open layout XML in Split view and don't show double design views so that the XML part is wide and workable as a code editor. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the blue icon on top:

[image: It says "Select Desgn Surface"]

It says "select design surfaces" or you can just press "B" on your keyboard.

Here you can choose between `Design and Blueprint`, `Blueprint` or just `Design`. When choosing just `Design` the blue layout disappears.

Comment: Did this resolve your porblem? Then please mark this as the solution...